# Applying sqrt function to multiple lists in clisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Newbie trying to learn Lisp. I want to apply sqrt (or any function) to several lists in Clisp. For eg. using mapcar we can apply to one list such as
    (mapcar #'sqrt ( 10 20 30)).

But what about cases where the lists are ((10 20) (30 40) (50)).  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
? (mapcar (lambda (e) (mapcar #'sqrt e)) '((10 20) (30 40) (50)))
((3.1622777 4.472136) (5.477226 6.3245554) (7.071068))
```

For arbitrary depths, you could use a recursive function:

```
(defun rmap (fun lst)
  (mapcar
   (lambda (x)
     (if (listp x)
       (rmap fun x)
       (funcall fun x)))
   lst))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there another way of doing the above using the apply function? Thanks.

Comment: @kevin You could replace `(funcall fun x)` by `(apply fun x nil)` or `(apply fun (list x))`.